# Using Qualtrics edit multiple choice to copy/paste responses

Tags: qualtrics

When creating a question of type multiple choice there is a facility that allows you to copy/paste a series of responses. Usually there is a link to the right called "edit multiple".
[[Expected Result]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUC8T.png)

Occasionally the link goes missing.
[[Missing Link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f585.png)

What causes this and how does one restore the link?

Answer (score 1):

Once the survey has responses or is activated that link goes away.  If you haven't activated the survey yet, delete all your preview/autotest responses and the "edit multiple" link should come back.